# How to get the number of last added record with PDO SQLite in PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, record

I have the sqlite-table with ID field that is PRIMARY_KEY. I add the new record to database by the next code:

```
$textQuery = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." VALUES ($numberRec,"."'".$a."'".",".$listNumbers.")";
$db->exec($textQuery);
```

Is there any simple way to define the number of last record to table in order to set $numberRec to needed value? Or I have to make SELECT and so on?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can do `$db->lastInsertId()`